# How to keep objects in NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c

There are two view controllers.One to add items,the other one to display(table view).All items are stored in an NSMutableArray.But every time I unwind to add item and when I go back to the table view, there is only the newest item left.

Code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   [self addData];
}

- (void)addData {

  if (!self.items) {
     self.items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 
  }
  [self.items addObject:self.textFromFirst];
}

// textFormFirst is an NSString which received from the previous view controller
```

---

add view controller

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

   UINavigationController *nav = [segue destinationViewController];
   SecondController *second = [nav.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

   second.textFromFirst = [self getText]; // get inputed string 
   self.aTextField.text = @"";
}
```

Comment: please add the code that launch the AddViewController

Comment: Show your storyboard. How are you "unwinding"?

Comment: every time you make a navigation, you are creating a new NSMutablearray.

Comment: @MuhammadWaqasBhati could u tell me the right way to do this?

Comment: That's because you always start with a fresh new instance of your view controller. If you need to persist the data, store it outside of it (save to disk, store in NSUserDefaults, static variable, ... whatever works best for your intention)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can share an `NSMutableArray` between your two view controllers. Just use a property:

**MainViewController**:

```
// .m
@interface MasterViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *items;

@end

@implementation MasterViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.items = [NSMutableArray array];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowDetail"]) {
        DetailViewController *controller = (DetailViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        controller.items = self.items;
        controller.textFromFirst = @"This is a test";
    }
}

@end
```

**AddViewController**:

```
// .h
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *textFromFirst;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *items;

@end

// .m
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self addData];
}   

- (void)addData {
    [self.items addObject:self.textFromFirst];
}
```

These is a sample project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ymum4zivgi0z688/TestUnwindSegue.zip?dl=0

---

I do not know why are you using array in AddViewController. Maybe you are prefer use unwind segue, like so:

```
// MainViewController.m
- (IBAction)saveItem:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {
    DetailViewController *detailVC = segue.sourceViewController;
    [self.items addObject:detailVC.textFromFirst];
}
```

In the case, you don't need to share an `NSMutableArray` to AddViewController.

Answer (score 0):

How are you persisting the NSMutableArray between view controllers? If you need to persist one array across your entire application I would suggest you use a **[singleton](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Singleton.html)**. A singleton is an object that *each instance* has only **1** memory address, thus is always the same object. You could accomplish this by doing the following:

**1)** Press CMD+N and select "Cocoa Touch Class" / subclass `NSMutableArray`

**2)** Go to that class' .m file and add the singleton in init

```
static YourNSMutableArray *highlander;

@implementation YourNSMutableArray

- (instancetype)init {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

        dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        highlander = [super init];

    });

   return highlander;
}
```

**3)** Now whenever you create a new instance in any of your view controllers like this

```
if (!self.items) {

    self.items = [YourNSMutableArray new]; 
}

[self.items addObject:self.textFromFirst];
```

`self.items` will always have the stored `self.textFromFirst` because any `YourNSMutableArray` you create in your app will always be the same object.

Comment: I think your way is right ,but the code doesn't work…Thanks

Comment: There are more than one ways to skin a cat. This though would be a way for you to achieve what you are looking for. I'm sorry you are having problems with the code. What's going wrong for you?

Comment: I am not familiar with singleton , I think I will  figure it out later.thanks again.I don't have enough reputation to vote…